# OwlCarousel crash display when nav back to page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel implemented in my website homepage, and it works fine when it's the first acccess to the page, but when I navigate to another page on my website and then click the button to go back to home page the directive crash and show images non formatted, see the example:

> First access to the page:
>   [image: that's the first access to the home page]
>
> That's when I nav to another page and go back to my home page, where the directive is:
>   [image: that's when I go back to the home page]

My HTML:

```html
<div class="carousel-wrap" ng-show="!internalControl.galleryShow">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="{{ slide.imagemUrl }}" alt="{{ slide.descritivo }}"/>
                <span class="img-text">{{ slide.descritivo }}</span>
            </a>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var owlCarousel = $('.owl-carousel');
    renderCarousel(owlCarousel);
})

function renderCarousel(owl) {
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        dots: false,
        navText: ["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'><i class='fa fa-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>", "<div class='nav-btn next-slide'><i class='fa fa-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>"],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1                        
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usa o evento 'pageshow' para montar o slider novamente ao clicar no voltar do navegador. Isso acontece pois o evento ready não é disparado ao voltar à página.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648785/679240

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function(){
    renderCarousel(owlCarousel);
});
```

Comment: Testei porém carrega apenas no primeiro acesso, quando faço o processo de voltar para a página inicial não chama a função pra carregar a diretiva. Sem o ng-repeat funciona.